# Working with string memory

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

Why `delete(pcResult);` rices exception in code below?

```
void strange(char *pcResul)
{
    CString  pss ="123";
    strncpy (pcResul,(LPCTSTR)pss,3);

}

void Dlg::OnBnClickedUser()
{
char *pcResult = new char (10);
strange(pcResult);
delete(pcResult);
}
```

Comment: Don't work with string memory. Use std::string.

Comment: If you are using MFC's `CString`, why even use a `char *`? The whole point of `CString` and `std::string` is to make dealing with strings easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only allocating a single character; then you write to it and two bytes of memory after it, giving undefined behaviour.

If you wanted to allocate an array of ten characters, then that's

```
char *pcResult = new char[10];
```

and needs to be deleted as an array

```
delete [] pcResult;
```

But, unless this is an exercise to learn about low-level memory shenanigans, use `std::string` to represent strings.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant:

```
void Dlg::OnBnClickedUser()
{
  char *pcResult = new char[10]; // Allocate an array of `char`, not char with value of 10.
  strange(pcResult);
  delete [] pcResult;
}
```